# Import JS files which uses DOM objects in a firefox Addon-sdk addon script

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hi i am currently working on a firefox Addon-sdk and i would like to know if there is a way to import JS files which uses DOM objects(like window) into the main.js code. I did use "mozIJSSubScriptLoader" but the addon keeps returning all the dom objects defined in the loaded scripts as "NOT DEFINED" and i think this should be because the main.js code does not have access to the DOM. Please, let me know if there is any other way to import/load these js files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need access to the entire JS doc in main.js? Typically you would execute whatever code you want on those objects in a contenct script then pass the results out to main.js

Comment: Well i have declared and initiated few variables in those files and i need to use those in main.js file. If there is anyway to get the varaible alone that would also work. The problem here is that the main.js does not accept DOM objects which is why my addon returns that window is undefined and also contentScriptFile does not have access to SDK modules. .  so i cannot use require and get Components import and import the files using mozIJSSubScriptLoader

Comment: I think the best solution will be to pass only the variables you need from the DOM objects into main.js using port.emit rather than trying to pass entire DOM objects.

Comment: So, i should include that file as a content script and get the variable using port.emit ? is that what you are saying ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to a window like this:

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var aXULBrowser = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
```

or you can enumerate through them all, that should be something in sdk/window/utils called "somethingEnumerateSomething"

Comment: How do i import a js using this aXULBrowser ? can you show me an example ? say the file name is test.js

Comment: Like access the content of a tab that is test.js?

Comment: Not a tab. Just the syntax which imports a js file

Comment: Oh I think i got you. Is the file a `file:///` path? Or a `chrome://` path? Or just something online so at a `http://`?

Comment: all the files are in my local machine.So, i use "self.data.url("path")" for contentscriptfile

Comment: you can only use `self.data.url(path)` for files located within your addons `data` folder. is that where your files are located?

Comment: Yes. That is where my files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in my other solution posted in this topic:

Posting as separate answer as I think the solution is totally different. If this is the right answer Ill delete my previous solution.

Check out the following:

- Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(uri.spec, global);

  - [MDN :: mozIJSSubScriptLoader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIJSSubScriptLoader)
- Components.utils.import

  - Example showing how to use it, and that in bootstrap you can only import in or after your `startup` function: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _template-BootstrapJSM.xpi](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387)
  - [MDN :: Components.utils.import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.import)

Comment: I have tried "mozlJSSubScriptLoader" already and have also mentioned this in my question. It can only include .jsm files and not .js

Comment: @MojoJojo did you use it like this: https://code.google.com/p/js-macosx/source/browse/trunk/demo/macosx%40mozilla.js/bootstrap.js#9 `var uri = o.Services.io.newURI(src, null, o.Services.io.newURI(__SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__, null, null));
 o.Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(uri.spec, global);` it should work

Comment: Have not tried it this way. Is it only for restartless addons or is it applicable for Addon-SDK as well ? because when i tried this i got an error saying "__SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__ is undefined"

Comment: Not that exact way, but have you made a uri out of the resource url made form the the `self.data.url('my file')`? that should work

Comment: i can import js files but cannot import js files which uses dom objects like navigator,window, etc. I know that this is because main.js does not have access to DOM and my question is that is there anyother way to do this ?

Comment: @MojoJojo the answer to that is the first solution I posted. You can use `getMostRecentBrowserWindow` which is equivalent of `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')` or you can access hidden window (have to let it load first on startup) with `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow`. Or you can enumerate through all windows with `var enum = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null/*or `navigator:browser`*/); while (enum.hasMoreElements()) { var aDOMWindow = enum.getNext(); }`.

Comment: To sum it up, to use DOM elements like canvas you'll have to access a DOM I think. You can use some DOM objects like File etc you have to import that with `Cu.importGlobalProperties(['File']);`

Comment: Cu.importGlobalProperties(['File']) does not work. Do you have any example code which i could refer ? sorry i am a begginer and a reference would be really helpful.

Comment: No problem. `importGlobalProperties` works for absolute certain, here's a super basic demo addon that uses it: https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/blob/master/bootstrap.js from sdk you would defined `Cu` by going `var {Cu, Ci} = require('chrome')`